# Makefile dependency chart

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, makefile, g++

I have this file:

```
main.c
A.h
A.c
B.h
B.c
X.h
```

and in main.c I include A and in A.h I include B and in B.h I include X.h 
How could I write makefile for this? please tell me about dependency diagram of this example

Comment: In `A.c` do you include `A.h`? In `B.c` do you include `B.h`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
main: main.o A.o B.o
    gcc -o main main.o A.o B.o

%.o: %.c
    gcc -c $<
```

While compiling the .c files you don't have to worry about dependencies yet, only when linking the executable.

Comment: what % mean here? (mean any?)

Comment: Yes, % is a placeholder that matches anything. The $< thing in the gcc command stands for the source file (what stands right of the colon, in this case, the .c file). There is also a variable $@ that stands for the target file (left of the colon), but we do not need it here because gcc automatically saves the compilation result of name.c as name.o.

Comment: @Aryan.. You need to learn the basics of Makefile `http://sagarsakre.blogspot.com/2012/09/understanding-makefile-for-beginners.html`